# Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager` from root provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2

У меня есть сервис в проекте ASP.NET Core 2.0

```
public class SomeSingletonService: IUserGetPropertiesService
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

   public SomeSingletonService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   public void SomeFunction() {
       // в этой строчке падает с ошибкой
       UserManager<User> userManager = _serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<User>>();
       // ...
   }
}
```

Сервис регистрируется как Singleton

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserGetPropertiesService,UserGetPropertiesService>();
```

При попытке получить `UserManager<User>` из `_serviceProvider` падает с ошибкой

> {System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[MyProject.Models.User]'
>   from root provider.

Не могу понять в чём дело, ведь в `SomeFunction` по идее можно получать scoped сервисы. Как мне в `SomeFunction` прокинуть `UserManager<User>`?

Не хочется ей передавать его в параметрах, так как тогда пришлось бы через всю логику приложения носить этот `UserManager<User>`, тогда как по идее можно его извлекать из Dependance Injection Container, который я пробую передать через конструктор - `IServiceProvider serviceProvider`

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой на версии 2.2, но по какой-то причине проблема возникала только в дебаге. В докере все прекрасно отрабатывало без проверки скоупа.

Answer (score 8):

Выяснилось что Scoped сервисы нужно получать через специальный блок

```
using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                        .CreateScope())
{
    UserManager<User> userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<User>>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Другое решение — отключить проверку областей видимости для сервисов, поставляемых средством DI. Это делается в Program.cs, найдите место создания `IWebHostBuilder` и добавьте:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false); // <==
```