# Создание scope: разница между IServiceProvider и IServiceScopeFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dependency-injection

В некотором asp.net mvc приложении (под .net core 2.1) мне понадобилось вручную cоздать scope для [фоновой задачи](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1). (Для 2.2 тоже актуально, но вроде [отличий](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) никаких нет)

И встречается мне два совершенно рабочих варианта на просторах сети, как это сделать.

Первый вариант построен на базе IServiceProvider ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481139/5752652)):

```
internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    public TimedHostedService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
    }

    private async Task Test()
    {
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
            await mediator.Send(new Application.Test.Command());
        }
    }
}
```

Второй вариант построен на базе IServiceScopeFactory ([пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760698/213987), [пример2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52862130/5752652)):

```
internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    public TimedHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
    }        

    private async Task Test()
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
            await mediator.Send(new Application.Test.Command());
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Не совсем понимаю, в чём между ними разница, если оба делают одну и ту же работу. Это как-то связано с разными подходами в core 2.1 и core 2.2? Или Microsoft в разных подразделениях сделала близкие вещи для одного и того же?

Какой способ предпочтительнее использовать в веб-приложениях? Не знаю, по каким параметрам мерять, ну допустим быстродействие или использование оперативной памяти.

Comment: Сама майкрософт в доке показала пример с IServiceProvider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если посмотреть как реализован метод `CreateScope` для `IServiceProvider`, то он реализован вот так:

```
return provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
```

Так что с точки зрения выполнения разницы тут нет. Однако, есть разница с точки зрения семантики:

- используя `IServiceScopeFactory`, вы явно декларируете, что будете создавать вложенные области;
- используя `IServiceProvider`, вы не декларируете ничего.

Кроме того, если вдруг ваш контейнер не поддерживает `IServiceScopeFactory` - то вариант с явным использованием этого класса упадёт при старте (что хорошо, ибо fail fast), а вариант с `IServiceProvider` - будет падать при каждой попытке исполнить задачу.