# Как перехватывать Exception в асинхронных методах?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, исключения, async-await

В приложении ASP.NET Core есть участок кода такого вида:

```cs
public class ContactsController : Controller {
        /// Для упрощения параметры и несущественные детали удалены.
        [HttpGet]
        public async void SomeGetMethod() {
        /// Операция тяжеловестная, поэтому максимально быстро отдаём ответ пользователю 
       /// и намеренно не ждём завершение операции!
            Task.Run(async () => {
                /// Какой-то код
                ...
                /// Тут exception
               throw new System.Exception("error");
            });
        }
}
```

Естественно этот Eexception не перехватывается ExceptionFilter'ом.

Встал вопрос как перехватывать такие исключения , так как было бы неплохо логировать эти случаи наиболее элегантным способом без написания try catch в каждом подобном асинхронном методе?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете Task.Run в уже асинхронном методе? Это же запускает код внутри Run в отдельном потоке, а SomeGetMethod дорабатывает до конца, и возвращает клиенту 'ничего'. К моменту, когда бросается исключение, возвращать ошибку уже некому. Метод вашего контроллера и так запускается в своем собственном потоке (поток под запрос), зачем эти манипуляции с Task.Run?

Comment: Это сделано специально для того что бы клиент не ждал ответа, он запускает некую тяжеловестную операцию окончание которой ему не надо ждать.

Comment: Чисто на заметку, как возможная альтернатива. В asp.net core начиная с 2.1 есть вполне удобный механизм фоновых задач ([тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/987911/213987)), клиент может просто сохранить задание в базу (как правило входные данные небольшие по объёму) и спокойно отваливаться, а задача сама стартанёт и обработается.

Comment: Можно через ContinueWith. Правда придется логер везде таскать.

Comment: @AK спасибо за совет, почитал оф доку про фоновые задачи, не не понял преимуществ против подхода с Task.Run. И не совсем понятны юзкейсы для чего онфоновые задачи  подходят.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, вроде бы фоновые задачи регистрируются, а задачи запущенные с помощью Task.Run - нет. Например, если IIS-у приспичит выгрузить домен приложения, то фоновая задача хотя бы имеет шанс доработать до своего завершения.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы метод вернул `Exception` необходимо:

1. Перед `Task.Run` использовать `await`.
2. Вместо `void` использовать `Task`.
   Таким образом, вы скажете `C#` что ваш метод будет работать в другом потоке, и по окончанию его работы вернётся его результат.

О асинхронных методах рекомендую почитать:
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php

Добавлю:
Создайте сервис и только через него запускайте все "сложные" таски пример ниже:
(Используйте входные параметры на ваше усмотрение)

```
public class TaskManagerService
{
    /***/

    public TaskManagerService(Logger logger)
    {
        /***/
    }

    public void Run(Action action)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //логируем
            }

        });
    }
}

public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private TaskManagerService taskManager;
    public FooController(TaskManagerService taskManager)
    {
        this.taskManager = taskManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void GetFoo()
    {
        taskManager.Run(() =>
        {
            //Сложная задача
        });
    }
}
```

И не забудьте его добавить в

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     //Если только для логирования используйте AddTransient
     service.AddTransient<TaskManagerService>()
}
```

Comment: по поводу использования await автор же ответил `Это сделано специально для того что бы клиент не ждал ответа, он запускает некую тяжеловестную операцию окончание которой ему не надо ждать.`

Comment: Какой смысл делать `ConfigureAwait` без, собственно, `await`?

Comment: Спасибо хороший вариант. Кстати я использую NET Core и поэтому `.ConfigureAwait(false);` не обязательно. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html И да соглашусь с @PavelMayorov надо передавать `Func<Task>` и вызывать так  `await action.Invoke()`

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov,@Vasya Milovidov  Согласен. Убрал.

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае мне может помочь такой хелпер. Ваше мнение?

```
public static class TaskHelper {
    public static void SafeRun(Func<Task> action) {
        Task.Run(async () => {
            try {
                await action.Invoke();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                /// логируем ошибку
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Только не `Action action`, а `Func<Task> action`. И дальше делать `await action.Invoke()`

Comment: Инстанс логера как протащите?

Comment: @Vasek я использую rollbar там один инстанс на все приложение (singleton)

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо! А почему именно так?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov а что если вам понадобится запускать асинхронную задачу?

Comment: @PavelMayorov зачем тогда `Task.Run` здесь? Это может быть просто асинхронный метод с `try/catch` и все дела. А вызывющий код если хочет - ждет конца операции, если не хочет - не ждет.

Comment: @tym32167 а `Task.Run` здесь, потому что асинхронная задача не обязана возвращать управление быстро.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну да, только если ради этого